# How get needed rows from 3 table in Laravel 5.5

Tags: php, laravel

I have 3 tables, Order, Products, Order_Products. I need get all field from order and products, thats ok using hasManyThrough(). But i need 1 more field from Order_products. How can i get this field ?

```
public function products()
{
   //in order model
 return $this->hasManyThrough('App\Models\Product','App\Models\OrderProduct','order_id','id','id','product_id');
}
```

using sql i need query like

SELECT
    `products`.*, `order_products`.`order_id`, `order_products`.`count` as `order_count`
FROM
    `products`
INNER JOIN `order_products` ON `order_products`.`product_id` = `products`.`id`
WHERE
    `order_products`.`order_id` = 2

Comment: You can use joins on your queries with the [query builder](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/queries#joins), or you can use the [relationship](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access intermediate table fields by using pivot attribute on model.

Lets say you have product, Then you can access count field of orders_products

```
$product->pivot->count;
```